# Deployer PHP - Custom command task always failed

Tags: php, command, task

in my Symfony 5.1 project I am trying to declare my own task which I would like to use when deploying. I created it like this:

```php
task('update_database', function () {
    if($_ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
    {
        cd('{{release_path}}');
        writeln('<info>Updating database</info>');
        run('{{bin/php}} {{bin/console}} d:d:c --if-not-exists');
        run('{{bin/php}} {{bin/console}} doctrine:schema:update --force');
    }
})->desc('Make database updates');
```

The "cd" and the "writeln" work. But every time I try to run a command it always fails

[image]

I tried with just the command `php bin/console` instead of using `{{bin/php}} {{bin/console}}`.

I even tried a silly `php bin/console cache:clear` command to see, but same error.

Yet I am in the right directory.. I followed this tutorial https://www.codepicky.com/php-automatic-deploy/

And I do the exact same thing though

**UPDATE :**

I connected to my server, I went to the last release of my project, and when I tried commands, absolutely nothing was happening. No mistake, but they didn't do anything. Even if I try the command to create an entity, it is "ignored".
The -vvv flag didn't give anything either

Here is what I have in the console:

[image]

Comment: Try to login to the server and run the command manually, the same as deployer runs. Also, all Symfony commands have an option to show more verbose output. Try to add `-vvv` (the highest mode), e.g. `[rest of the command] cache:clear -vvv`, it can give you some hints why they're failed

Comment: I took your advice, and made a strange discovery. I updated my 1st post with the details. I have to admit that I don't understand

Comment: Perhaps, something went wrong with PHP on the server. Try to run `php -r "echo 1;"` or `php -i`. 
Not sure if it makes any sense, but who knows: try to create a silly php script manually on the server and run it. Something like `echo "<?php echo 123;" > test.php && php test.php`

Comment: Okay I found the error. I am completely stupid. In fact, on the last release, there was a bug when I deployed it, so the vendors didn't install. Suddenly no command could work, logical. I deleted the last release, I redeployed, and I took care to put my task after the one that installs the vendors. And everything works. Sorry for the inconvenience !

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. Btw, I could also find it if noticed that there were no a `vendor` folder that should exist on 99% PHP projects